# Is it possible to run MySQL server from a conda environment?

Tags: mysql, conda

I have installed [mysql-server](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mysql-server) in a conda environment (if the package exists, I assume the server can run from such environment, right?). I'm not sure how can I start the server though.

Edit: I should have mentioned that I tried `systemctl start mysqld`, but I got `Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.`

Comment: Seems like you need to spend a little time learning how to use MySQL now you have one to play with

Comment: @RiggsFolly can't see how your comment help me out in that direction you're referring to. Mind sharing some actionable knowledge, if you have it ;-)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The manual is where you need to start https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/starting-server.html And you will need to become familiar with it for many reasons. This is not a coding question

Comment: @RiggsFolly riiight, right right

Comment: You may get more traction if you ask this on the [Database Administrator Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)